# How to add color picker in a row of Ext.grid.GridPanel

Tags: extjs, color-picker, gridpanel

I'd like to use a color picker when I edit some cells in a row of an Ext.grid.GridPanel.
I didn't find any examples from the official Examples or the APIs, could someone give me some example codes for this case, any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [plugin](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?73998-3.x-Ext.ux.ColorPickerField) on sencha forum for extjs3. It seems that you can use it as an `editor` for your grid.

Comment: thanks mate, it really helps and the plugin download url is :http://www.sencha.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=20361&d=1273220386